# Flex applications on Azure

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, azure, flash-builder

I plan to deploy my Flex Application on the web using MS Azure. Has anyone done this?
If yes, can you please provide pointers, reference links etc?

Regards
Aparna

Answer (score 0):

As far as Azure is concerned, your swfs are just resources so your'e basically looking at a regular though pimped ISP. The interesting possibility is connecting it to Azure backend, possibly with SQL Azure.

As far as I can see. FluorineFX should work there as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the static content, html/swf/... then I suggest you use blob storage to put them in instead of using compute power of several instances as these are not needed. This will cut down on your costs as blob storage is publicly accessible but is very cheap.

If your Flex application needs integration with services then you need to host them in a compute environment like an instance.